BCa bootstrap CI adjusts for bias in median difference of groups A-B, but not the opposite direction
I'm using the boot-package in R to calculate a BCa bootstrap interval for the median difference between two groups A and B of a waiting time, rounded to days. Following the notation in boot, let the median difference from the original sample be $t0$, and the bootstrap replications of the median is $t$.
The waiting times for each group are long tailed but with most of the mass centered at a small set of discrete values. Overall, the bootstrap distribution places 20% of the mass to the left of $t0$, 40% of the mass at $t0$, and 40% to the right of $t0$. The overall sample size is around 100 for each group.
What was surprising to me is that I note substantial differences for BCa confidence intervals depending on whether I estimate the "group A median - group B median" compared to the "group B median - group A median." This is not the case for the percentile CI, as the change of direction only flips the bootstrap distribution around the y-axis, t the 2.5th percentile from one direction corresponds to the 97.5th percentile of the flipped bootstrap distribution.
But the bias correction parameter $z_0$ in BCa effectively rearranges the $\alpha=0.05$ a lot more in the B-A direction than in the A-B-direction, due to the 20/40/40-distribution around $t0$.
$$ z_0 = \Phi^{-1}(\Sigma(t<t0)/B)$$
For my data, In A-B, the percentiles of the bootstrap distribution when using BCa become 0.0001 and 0.6, while in the B-A direction, it's 0.01 and 0.92. The boot package rightfully throws warnings about "BCa Intervals used Extreme Quantiles, Some BCa intervals may be unstable".
[]
If I trust that the bias correction is doing something sensible (but I'm not sure, see below), it's telling me that as there is a strong bias to the 40%-side, and a bias adjusted median difference should be pushed strongly towards the 20%-side, as far out in the 20%-side tail that we can't actually trust the bootstrap distribution to be reliable in the extreme tail.
But I wonder if this is not more related to a lot of mass being centered at $t0$, which I would not consider bias. Possible solutions to get symmetric bounds is to distribute the mass at $t0$ evenly, e.g. by smoothing the bootstrap (e.g. with adding Uniform[-0.5, 0.5] to each original waiting time), or less involved, cutting the mass at $t0$ in half and attributing it to each tail, i.e.
$$ z_0 = \Phi^{-1}((\Sigma(t<t0)  + 1/2 \Sigma(t = t0))/B)$$
Using this definition gives me symmetric results, i.e. the same results for the lower bound of A-B and the upper bound of B-A.
Would be very happy to hear any comments on this, if one can motivate this splitting from some assumption made in BCa, or if you see any potential issues with the proposal etc.
Edit in response to whuber: The results are consistent using different seeds, and using 5000 replications give consistent results across different batches. Also added an image to highlight the issue.

Could you describe the evidence you have that the procedures give inequivalent results?  After all, bootstrap results are random, so you need to examine much more than a single pair of answers.

Thanks for the reply whuber.
The differences are consistent across different seeds, and I run enough replications to get consistent results as long as I keep the order (A-B or B-A) the same. So I'm not worried about the randomness. I added an image to highlight the issue more clearly, and also added some ideas on how to solve it.

The BCa adjustment tries to deal with both bias and skew. What happens if you use the "basic" (or "empirical") bootstrap instead of the percentile bootstrap? See this page. That might help distinguish the bias part from the skew part, although I fear that your situation might be too inconsistent with the assumption of a "pivotal" statistic for the bootstrap (or at least the acceleration correction) to be reliable.
